# Exchange Server mails not received with FAIL AGENT in logs

Tags: exchange, exchange-2013

using exchange server 2013;

A few of exchange users are complaining that they are not receiving emails from a certain domain's certain users. I have checked the sender domains and domain is not found in any BL and domains SPF records are good as well.

so situation is

> user1@externaldomain.com sends to myuser@mydomain.com and mail is
>   received. User2@externaldomain.com  sends to myuser@mydomain.com and
>   mail is not received. User3@externaldomain.com  sends to
>   myuser@mydomain.com and mail is not received.

And a similar complain is made by another user. So, I check a few things and found something in Message tracking…

```
[PS] C:\Windows\system32>Get-MessageTrackingLog -Server MYSERVER -Start "02/19/2019 02:00:00" -End "02/20/2019 16:00:00" -Recipients "myuser@mydomain.com”

HARED... SMTP     user1@externaldomain.com                 {myuser@mydomain.com}
RECEIVE  SMTP     user1@externaldomain.com                 {myuser@mydomain.com}
FAIL     AGENT    user1@externaldomain.com                 {myuser@mydomain.com}
AGENT... AGENT    user1@externaldomain.com                 {myuser@mydomain.com}
HARED... SMTP     user1@externaldomain.com                 {myuser@mydomain.com}
RECEIVE  SMTP     user1@externaldomain.com                 {myuser@mydomain.com}
FAIL     AGENT    user1@externaldomain.com                 {myuser@mydomain.com}
AGENT... AGENT    user1@externaldomain.com                 {myuser@mydomain.com}
```

I am not sure what is happening. why and what is causing that FAIL

Here are some more details

```
[PS] C:\Windows\system32>get-ContentFilterConfig

RunspaceId                            : dd89fbfd-2586-406a-a43f-00c61164159d
Name                                  : ContentFilterConfig
RejectionResponse                     : Message rejected as spam by Content Filtering.
OutlookEmailPostmarkValidationEnabled : True
BypassedRecipients                    : {}
QuarantineMailbox                     :
SCLRejectThreshold                    : 7
SCLRejectEnabled                      : True
SCLDeleteThreshold                    : 9
SCLDeleteEnabled                      : False
SCLQuarantineThreshold                : 9
SCLQuarantineEnabled                  : False
BypassedSenders                       : {}
BypassedSenderDomains                 : { externaldomain.com, externaldomain2.com, paypa.com, CCC.net, gmail.com, microsoft.com}
Enabled                               : True
ExternalMailEnabled                   : True
InternalMailEnabled                   : False
AdminDisplayName                      :
ExchangeVersion                       : 0.1 (8.0.535.0)
DistinguishedName                     : CN=ContentFilterConfig,CN=Message Hygiene,CN=Transport
                                        Settings,CN= MYDOMAIN,CN=Microsoft
                                        Exchange,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=MYDOMAIN,DC=com
Identity                              : ContentFilterConfig
Guid                                  : 5091c1d6-14da-41db-b651-5c09135de269
ObjectCategory                        : MYDOMAIN/Configuration/Schema/ms-Exch-Message-Hygiene-Content-Filter-Con
                                        fig
ObjectClass                           : {top, msExchAgent, msExchMessageHygieneContentFilterConfig}
WhenChanged                           : 2/13/2019 12:17:42 AM
WhenCreated                           : 4/29/2015 2:26:41 AM
WhenChangedUTC                        : 2/13/2019 8:17:42 AM
WhenCreatedUTC                        : 4/29/2015 9:26:41 AM
OrganizationId                        :
OriginatingServer                     : ADS.MYDOMAIN.com
IsValid                               : True
ObjectState                           : Unchanged
```

If you notice I have already set some domains in "BypassedSenderDomains" and externaldomain.com has already been added and my spam agent logs are showing that as well, and here are some spam agent logs

```
2019-02-20T02:28:52.455Z,08D6667109583CE6,xx.xx.xxx.xxx:2525,xx.xx..0.100:61670,xx.xx..0.100,<DB7P193MB03958494272A2C15517BE7F7AA7D0@DB7P193MB0395.EURP193.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM>,user1@externaldomain.com,user1@externaldomain.com;,myuser@mydomain.com,1,Content Filter Agent,OnEndOfData,AcceptMessage,,SCL,not available: content filtering was bypassed.,,d70d3909-03ce-4458-3f21-08d696db2785,,Incoming

2019-02-20T02:30:25.064Z,08D6667109583CE6,xx.xx.xxx.xxx:2525,xx.xx..8.115:26160,xx.xx..8.115,<DB7P193MB0395D65CF9FA48BAAA779366AA7D0@DB7P193MB0395.EURP193.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM>,user1@externaldomain.com,user1@externaldomain.com;,myuser@mydomain.com,1,Content Filter Agent,OnEndOfData,AcceptMessage,,SCL,not available: content filtering was bypassed.,,f612e78e-b3f0-4987-5969-08d696db5eb8,,Incoming

2019-02-20T05:03:04.567Z,08D6667109583D5F,xx.xx.xxx.xxx:2525,xx.xx..14.131:24231,xx.xx..14.131,<DB7P193MB0395AB0AA0027FECA619C88BAA7D0@DB7P193MB0395.EURP193.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM>,user1@externaldomain.com,user1@externaldomain.com;,myuser@mydomain.com,1,Content Filter Agent,OnEndOfData,AcceptMessage,,SCL,not available: content filtering was bypassed.,,ccc92992-4a25-4a7f-9627-08d696f0b235,,Incoming

2019-02-20T06:42:41.796Z,08D6667109583DB4,xx.xx.xxx.xxx:2525,xx.xx..2.120:45283,xx.xx..2.120,<DB7P193MB0395E5E84AD36322A620F6A9AA7D0@DB7P193MB0395.EURP193.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM>,user1@externaldomain.com,user1@externaldomain.com;,myuser@mydomain.com,1,Content Filter Agent,OnEndOfData,AcceptMessage,,SCL,not available: content filtering was bypassed.,,085ea7bd-add4-43f2-4d93-08d696fe9cea,,Incoming

2019-02-20T09:36:35.505Z,08D6667109583E99,xx.xx.xxx.xxx:2525,xx.xx..5.98:42760,xx.xx..5.98,<AM5P193MB0020E28194DFBEC6E1A4B99EA57D0@AM5P193MB0020.EURP193.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM>,user2@externaldomain.com,user2@externaldomain.com;,myuser@mydomain.com,1,Content Filter Agent,OnEndOfData,AcceptMessage,,SCL,not available: content filtering was bypassed.,,439ae10c-c673-45fc-f7c2-08d69716e7e3,,Incoming
```

Please advise what i need to check to make sure that my user always receives mails from a certain domain.

Thank you 
Ali

Answer (score 1):

Since the event type is fail and the source is agent, it refers to the transport agent, which is being blocked by a transport rule.  Have you had a look at the transport config yet? Here's a similar thread for your reference:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/27072b07-6d54-47c4-a724-eaecd9e5aebd/transport-rules-and-message-tracking?forum=exchangesvrsecuremessaginglegacy